# Remove unwanted texting in Terminal

Tags: gpio, sensor, lxterminal

I have accessed Temperature and Analog Pressure sensor to the RPI. But for some reason There are text display before Temperature sensor start to give values.[image: Terminal Display of Tem. Sensor]

Also since I'm using Picocom to take Pressure sensor's Serial value which has  produced by Arduino, It also start with such a display and start to give values.[image: Terminal Display of Pressure Sensor]

Have any idea how to remove those as sensors start to give values?

Comment: If you want to remove the errors you need to remove or comment out the bad lines as indicated in the messages.  As to the rest of the question I don't understand what you want.  Could you **EDIT** your question to show the output you want from the Pi?

Comment: since where the sensor reading show up.

Answer (score 1):

Those are usually printed to STDERR. Use `cmd 2>/tmp/cmd_errors.log` to redirect them. Best to fix them, but it’s your Pi.